# Suppose $A^{\text{'}} $ is the set of limit point of $A$. Prove $A^{\text{'}} $ is closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Good morning i was thinking this problem but i cannot solve, please help me.

Problem:

Suppose $A^{\text{'}}  $ is the set of limit point  of $A$. Prove $A^{\text{'}}  $ is closed set.

I make this:

Because $A^{\text{'}}  $ is the limit point  of $A$ then $A\cap B\left(p:r\right)\neq\phi\;p\:\text{∈}\:\mathbb{R}$ and $A^{\text{'}}  $ $=\left\{ p_{1},p_{2},...\right\} $ now, how can i prove $A^{\text{'}}  $ $=\left\{ p_{1},p_{2},...\right\} $ is a closed set? Help me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about your notation, but it looks like you are in $\mathbb{R}$ or at least a metric space. It suffices to see that the limit points of $A'$ are contained in $A'$. Let $x$ be a limit point of $A'$. We need to show that $x$ is in $A'$. That is, we need to show that $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then $B(x:\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \cap A' \neq \emptyset$, as $x$ is a limit point of $A'$.

Let $y \in B(x:\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \cap A'$. Then as $y \in A'$, $B(y:\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Let $z \in B(y:\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \cap A)$. Then
$$d(z,x) \leq d(z,y) + d(y,x) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$
Thus $z \in B(x:\varepsilon)$. Since $z \in A$ as well, $z \in B(x:\varepsilon) \cap A$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitary, this shows that $x \in A'$. Therefore the limit points of $A'$ are contained in $A'$, and so $A'$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be in the complement of $A'$, and suppose for every $\epsilon>0$ the ball of radius $\epsilon, B(x;\epsilon)$ contains some point of $A$.  Then in particular, we can let $q_k \in A \cap B\left ( x; \frac{1}{k} \right )$, thus the sequence $\{q_k\}$ converges to the point $x$.  Contradiction.

Comment: I don't see de Contradiction, can you explain? Thanks!

Comment: There exists a neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $A$.  If this neighborhood contained a point of $A'$ then this yields a contradiction.  Think about it for a bit.  Take some time to work on this problem for a bit.  Not everyone is here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Most proofs of this assume a metric space. Since you didn't specify, here's a proof for any topology. Assume $A'$ is not closed, so $\exists q \in {A'}' - A'$. There must exist an open nighborhood $O$ of q that does not contain any elements of A. (else q would be a limit point of $A$ and in $A'$). Since q is a limit point of $A'$ and $q\notin A'$ there must be a point $p\in A'$ in $O$. Since p is a limit point of A and $p\notin A$ there must be a point $s\in A$ in $O$. This contradicts our assumption that $A \cap O = \emptyset$. So ${A'}' = A'$ and $A'$ is closed.